# what is the significance of placing a variable inside a for loop rather than outside in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I don't think this is a matter of global-local variables as the duplicate bot suggested because when I edited the wrong code and placed the counter variable inside the for loop, the same wrong output was given.

I was trying to write a function which counts the number of instances an input word/character occurs.

the test data were :

1- input (find('The quick brown fox', 'fox'))   , output (“fox was found 1 times”)

2- input (find('aa, bb, cc, dd, aa', 'aa'))  , output(“aa was found 2 times”)

I have attempted to solve it two times, first time the output was ”fox was found 6.333333 times ” and the second solution gave an output “fox was found 1 times”.

The difference between the two methods I attempted was the position of the final output counter and the syntax used.

first attempt:

```
function find(str,key){ 
var count = 0;
var answer = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i<str.length; i++){ 
        if (str[i] == key[0] ){
            for (var j = i; j<i +str.length; j++){
                if (str[j] == key[j-i]){ 
                    count = count + 1;
                }       
            }
        }
    }

    answer = (count)/(key.length);
    return key + "was found " + answer + "times";

}
```

second attempt:

```
function find(str,key){ 
var count = 0;
var answer = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i<str.length; i++){ 

        if (str[i] == key[0] ){ 

            for (var j = i; j<i +str.length; j++){    

                if (str[j] == key[j-i]){  
                    count = count + 1;
                }

                if (count == key.length){answer = answer + 1;}
            }
        }
    }
    return key + "was found " + answer + "times";
}
```

I am not sure why the first one did not work, and what happened inside my code that yielded an answer of 6.3333 rather than 1?

Comment: [***This***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/easiest-way-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-javascript-array) may help you, but you have two different inputs with & without comma.

Comment: You're dividing count by key.length in the first example, hence why you get a decimal value (19/3 = 6.333). The second example only increments answer, hence why it's an integer value.

Comment: @ManoDestra yes I understand the output can be decimal when division happens, but in my case and if my maths is correct, count should be 3 and key.length also 3, therefore output is supposed to be 1 not 6.3333

Comment: Somehow, it is picking up the length of the input string, rather than the length of the array.

Comment: @ManoDestra it's obvious that count was calculated to be 19, therefore when divided by 3 the output was 6.3333, so my question was why count was 19 rather than 3

Comment: @ManoDestra yeah, not sure why it counts the string length, probably something wrong with my function

Comment: My guess is that you accidentally had a single = in there somewhere instead of ==. That way your variable could have been overwritten with a string variable. And the length would then be 19, rather than the length of the previously stored array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems in you first attempt, see comments in the (fixed) code below

```
function find(str,key){ 
    var count = 0;
    var answer = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i<str.length; i++){ 
        if (str[i] == key[0] ){
            for (var j = i; j<str.length; j++){  // you have to stop at end of "str"!
                if (str[j] == key[j-i]){ 
                    count = count + 1;
                }
                else {
                    break; // no match, you have to restart at beginning of "key"
                }       
            }
        }
    }

    answer = (count)/(key.length);
    return key + "was found " + answer + "times";

}
```

NB there's a third problem that's potentially fixed by your 2nd version (potentially because there's bugs in it too). The problem is that partial matches should count for zero and not `n/key.length` (an example is provided in the comments by @TheGreatContini).

While we're at it, here is a fix to the 2nd one

```
function find(str,key){ 
    var count = 0;
    var answer = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i<str.length; i++){ 

        if (str[i] == key[0] ){ 

            for (var j = i; j<str.length; j++){ // same problem here

                if (str[j] == key[j-i]){  
                    count = count + 1;
                }
                else { 
                    count = 0;
                    break; // you have to restart
                }

                if (count == key.length){
                     count = 0;   // a new beginning
                     answer = answer + 1;
                 }
            }
        }
    }
    return key + "was found " + answer + "times";
}
```

**PS** as a bonus, [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/z-algorithm-linear-time-pattern-searching-algorithm/) is a more efficient string matching algorithm - `O(str.length)` instead of `O(str.length*key.length)`.

Comment: You could drop the else by moving the if condition into the condition on the for loop.

Comment: @Trisped that's right, it would be shorter, but harder to comment the change and point the problem of the original code.

Comment: @TheGreatContini the result is `count / key.length`, so it is fine.

Comment: Referring to first code only: It is wrong to implement `count` for partial word matches.  This code will produce wrong answers for a number of cases.  Try for example find('aa aa aa aa', 'ab')).  The code should output 0 matches, but this code will not get the right answer.

Comment: The second code has issues to: you need to init `count` to 0 every time before the `for j` loop is ran.

Comment: @TheGreatContini yes, that's fixed. About the first one, that's another call - it indeed isn't right, but it answers the question for the examples given.

Comment: @TheGreatContini I've updated the answer, thanks for your comments.

Comment: @Ilya Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You're dividing count by key.length in the first example, hence why you get a decimal value (19/3 = 6.333, where 19 is the length of the input). The second example only increments answer, hence why it's an integer value.

Comment: Thanks @ManoDestra

Answer (score 1):

Every time you do a `for j` loop, you need to initialise count to 0.

A new loop is the beginning of a new word comparison.  You only increment answer if count reaches the full length of the word.  So you are always going to need a `if (count == key.length){answer = answer + 1;}`.

BTW, your `for i` loop should not go up to `str.length`, instead subtract `key.length` from it.

Comment: That's very unclear. What version are you referring to ?